# How to search for truncated data with the original data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Here is a database structure to illustrate my question

```sql
CREATE TABLE `company` (
    `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `name` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I add a company that has a name longer than 10 characters it will be truncated. So when I search the company with its full name I cannot find it.

**Question**: How can I get the maximum length of the « name » column which is 10 in this example to be able to truncate and do the research with « SUBSTRING() »

> NB : The context doesn’t permit to change the maximum length of the
> name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by querying the `information_schema`.  Something like this should work for you.

```
select character_maximum_length 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema = database()
   and table_name = 'company'
   and column_name = 'name'
```

You'll get a one row resultset with the length you want.

You can make this into part of your query with a (nasty!) query pattern like this.

```
select company_id, name
  from company
  where name = substring('A long search string', 1, (
                    select character_maximum_length 
                      from information_schema.columns 
                     where table_schema = database()
                       and table_name = 'company'
                       and column_name = 'name') )
```

Or you could try this (more readable) consecutive pair of queries using a session variable.

```
select @max :=  character_maximum_length 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema = database()
   and table_name = 'hotels'
   and column_name = 'name' ;

select company_id, name
  from company
  where name = substring('A long search string', 1, @max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you're searching something like

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE company = LEFT('something longer than 10 chars', 10);
```

?

- `LEFT()` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

To get the length of a varchar column you have to query the information_schema.

```
SELECT character_maximum_length 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND table_name = 'company'
AND column_name = 'name';
```

So your query becomes

```
SELECT * 
FROM company 
WHERE company = LEFT('something longer than 10 chars', (
    SELECT character_maximum_length 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
    AND table_name = 'company'
    AND column_name = 'name';
)
);
```

Comment: No, I would like to automatically get the "10", the max length of the column

Comment: @kenfire Edited my answer.